# Xcode, extracting views from a storyboard to a nib, best approach?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I need to extract some repeating complexity from a storyboard, probably to a nib file, so I can reuse it, to overcome some recurring autolayout constraint issues.

To elaborate, inside a view I have several labels / views and another view underneath. This is repeated several times.

I've tried to copy and paste these into to a nib file, however I lose some of the constraints also the width and height of the selections I copied.

I just wondered if there's a technique to extracting these into a nib.

Everytime I try, I create a new nib and paste, I end up with a real mess.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying it from the VC to a view in the same storyboard.  If that works, make a copy of the resulting storyboard file and edit it down to just that view.